# Getting the error Type 'Observable<{}>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<User>'. when trying to use @ngrx/store's store.select()

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, ngrx, rxjs5

I am trying to set my `$currentUser` after an API call, but I keep getting the error:

```
[default] 
Type 'Observable<{}>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<User>'.
  Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'User'.
    Property 'username' is missing in type '{}'.
```

My component that's throwing the error looks like this:

```
import {Component, state} from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from "rxjs";

import { User } from '../../../../models/user';
import { Store } from '@ngrx/store';
import { AppState } from '../../../../reducers';
import {UserService} from "../../../../services/user.service";

@Component({
  selector: 'user-center',
  templateUrl: 'user-center.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['user-center.component.scss']
})
export class UserCenter {
  $currentUser: Observable<User>;
  userService: UserService;
  constructor(
    userService: UserService,
    public store: Store<AppState>
  ) {
    this.userService = userService;
    this.$currentUser = this.store.select('user');
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.userService.initialise();
  }
}
```

My Effect looks like this::

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Effect, StateUpdates, toPayload } from '@ngrx/effects';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

import { AppState } from '../reducers';
import { UserService } from '../services/user.service';
import { UserActions } from "../actions/UserActions";

@Injectable()
export class UserEffects {
  constructor(
    private updates$: StateUpdates<AppState>,
    private userService: UserService,
    private userActions: UserActions,
  ) {}


  @Effect() CurrentUser$ = this.updates$
    .whenAction('INIT_USER')
    .switchMap(() => this.userService.getUser()
      .map(user => this.userActions.setCurrentUser(user))
      .catch(() => Observable.of({ type: 'GET_USER_FAILED' })
      ));
}
```

Comment: after upgrading to angular-cli beta 14 , I'm getting the same kind of errors

Comment: I am also using Angular-cli,but still on Webpack. 8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should change your constructor and set dependency to Store as `public store: Store<User>`. Or do you really need it to be as `Store<AppState>`? The type should be set automatically using generics [`src/operator/select.ts`](https://github.com/ngrx/core/blob/master/src/operator/select.ts):

```
constructor(
    userService: UserService,
    public store: Store<User>
) {
    this.userService = userService;
    this.$currentUser = this.store.select('user');
}
```

Alternatively, the error is thrown because you define `$currentUser` as:

```
$currentUser: Observable<User>;
```

so you can use [type assertion in TypeScript](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec.md#416-type-assertions) when assigning the data to `this.$currentUser`:

```
this.$currentUser = <Observable<User>>this.store.select('user');
```